# ERROR PIP INSTALL Paquetes o Librerías en python en UBUNTU

Tags: python, visual-studio, linux, terminal, gnu

Hola amigos quiero instalar Numpy desde la terminal de Visual Studio Code,pero no me sale error, de echo me salen dos ERRORES abajo les dejo los errores. (Ya intente actualizar el pip3)

1-ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

**AL LEER EL ERROR QUISE ACTUALIZAR EL PIP3 PERO ME SALE ESTE OTRO ERROR.**

2- Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Si a alguien le ha pasado le agradezco su ayuda por favor!!!

Comment: Ya tienes instalado openssl?

Comment: Lo instale también... Pero, igual me dice que actualice pip. Actualizo pip pero me da error siempre.